# mvc3 best way to remove a .tolist in global

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, foreach, listings

I have a model which is a **tolist and its ordered by date**  and then i have a foreach in the **view model** I was wondering how can i get a craigslist like effect when displaying the Date, .. if you look at the foreach below it is grouped as 
**1. Date, profile, state

2. Date, profile, state**
 and so on.

How can I turn that into

**Date

1. profile, state

2. profile, state**

as everything is ordered by the createDate, I would like to display the Date like 4-21-2013 and 
then under that date all of the listings created on it.. then on 4-20-2013 and the same thing. I do not know if it can be done in a foreach any help would be great !!

```
// the controller model
var mypages = (from s in db.jobs.OrderBy(c => c.createDate) select s).ToList();


 // the view model
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   @item.createDate ,
@Html.ActionLink("View profile", "detail", "profile", new { id = item.profile}),
@item.state 
}
```

Comment: Store the last date in a variable. If the date is different or more or equal to a day more. Display the date and the re-store that date in the lastdate variable.

Comment: Thank you just tried it ..works great.